# Determine, if there is one, the point of intersection between the line given by the equation:

Tags: geometry, vectors

The equation for the line is
\begin{equation}
\frac{x-5}{2} = 1 - y = \frac{z - 15}{4}
\end{equation}

The equation for the plane is
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ 
                       y \\ 
                       z \end{array}\right) = 
\left(\begin{array}{r} -2 \\ 
                       -7 \\ 
                       5 \end{array}\right) + s
\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 
                       6 \\ 
                       3 \end{array}\right) + t
\left(\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 
                       4 \\ 
                       -1 \end{array}\right)                   
\end{equation}

What I'm not really sure about is how to convert the vector equation into the general equation of the form
\begin{equation}
ax + by + cz + d = 0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

From eqt of plane 
$\begin{align}&x=-2+2s+t\\&y=-7+6s+4t\\&z=5+3s-t\\\end{align}
\implies$ $$ \begin{align}&{{x-5}\over 2}={{-7}\over2}+s+{t\over2} \tag{1}\\ \\&1-y=8-6s-4t \tag{2}\\ \\&{{z-15}\over 4}={{-5}\over2}+{{3s}\over4}-{t\over 4} \tag{3}\\\end{align}$$
<strike>Clearly $\require{cancel}\cancel{(1) \ne (2)\ne (3) \implies}$ no intersection</strike>

---

**EDIT**:
Following David Peterson's answer and comment, it was nonsensical of me to infer non-intersection if ${(1) \ne (2)\ne (3)}$. Rather the three equations form a set of simultaneous equations which must be solved; if a solution is obtained we can then infer intersection else not.

Comment: Does this make sense to anybody?

Comment: I solve the above system and obtain s=1,t=1, and so x=1, y=3, z=7

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation of the plane as $\mathbf x = \mathbf a + s\mathbf b + t\mathbf c$, and the equation of the line as

$$\mathbf x = (5,-1,15) + u(2, -1, 4) = \mathbf d + u\mathbf e$$

Then we want $s,t,u$ such that $\mathbf a + s\mathbf b + t\mathbf c = \mathbf d + u\mathbf e$. You can solve this for e.g. $s$ by taking the scalar product with $\mathbf c \times \mathbf e$; since $\mathbf c \cdot (\mathbf c \times \mathbf e) = \mathbf e \cdot (\mathbf c \times \mathbf e) = 0$, we get

$$s\mathbf b \cdot (\mathbf c \times \mathbf e) = (\mathbf d - \mathbf a) \cdot (\mathbf c \times \mathbf e)$$

And similarly for $t,u$.

Answer (score 1):

A normal to your plane is

$$\vec n = (2,6,3)\times (1,4,-1) = (-18,5,2)$$

The direction vector to your line is $\vec d = (2,-1,4)$.

Notice $\vec n \cdot \vec d \neq 0$, so they are not orthogonal, hence the line must intersect the plane.

In the manner in which K. Rmth began, we have

$$-7/2 + s + t/2 = k$$
$$8 - 6s + -4t = k$$
$$-5/2 + 3s/4 - t/4 = k$$

Said another way

$$s + t/2 - k = 7/2$$
$$ 6s + -4t - k = -8$$
$$ 3s/4 - t/4 - k = 5/2$$

Solving this system yields $s=1, t=1, k=-2$, and hence there is an intersection at $(x,y,z)=(1,3,7)$

Comment: how did you solve the system?

Comment: In this instance I used software (lazy), but solving a system of this size is usually taught in high school or in "intermediate" algebra. Here is what I did: http://goo.gl/gthdZN, more info on solving systems: http://goo.gl/HDT4Jn